# Is There Any Way To Update String Array From Online File (Android)

Tags: android, inputstream, updates, arrays, android-internet

i am working on an image gallery app in which i am loading images from URL. i have stored image URLs in a string array:

```
public static String[] IMAGES = new String[]{
     "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q",
     "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q",
     "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q",
     };
```

but how can i update string array from online file instead of adding URLs manually, 
Is There Any Way To Update String Array From Online File

full code:

```
package com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader;


public final class Constants {

    public static final String[] IMAGES = new String[] {

            "http://tabletpcssource.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/android-logo.png",
            "http://simpozia.com/pages/images/stories/windows-icon.png",
            "http://radiotray.sourceforge.net/radio.png",
            "http://www.bandwidthblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/twitter-logo.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100907_itunes1.png",
            "http://weloveicons.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/100929_applications.png",
            "http://www.idyllicmusic.com/index_files/get_apple-iphone.png",
            "http://www.frenchrevolutionfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/Twitter-Bird.png",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ka5MiRGJ_S4/TdD9OoF6bmI/AAAAAAAAE8k/7ydKtptUtSg/s1600/Google_Sky%2BMaps_Android.png",
            "http://www.desiredsoft.com/images/icon_webhosting.png",
            "http://goodereader.com/apps/wp-content/uploads/downloads/thumbnails/2012/01/hi-256-0-99dda8c730196ab93c67f0659d5b8489abdeb977.png",
            "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mlaJ4p_3rBU/TdD9OWxN8II/AAAAAAAAE8U/xyynWwr3_4Q/s1600/antivitus_free.png",
            "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transformers/computer.png",
            "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/firefox.png?7794fe",
            "https://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market/com.rovio.angrybirdsseasons/hi-256-9-347dae230614238a639d21508ae492302340b2ba",
            "http://androidblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/tablet-pc-256x256.jpg",
            "http://www.theblaze.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Apple.png",
            "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-y-HQwQ4Kuu0/TdD9_iKIY7I/AAAAAAAAE88/3G4xiclDZD0/s1600/Twitter_Android.png",
            "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nAf4IMJGpc8/TdD9OGNUHHI/AAAAAAAAE8E/VM9yU_lIgZ4/s1600/Adobe%2BReader_Android.png",
            "http://cdn.geekwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/oovoo-android.png?7794fe",
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kocco/ndroid/128/android-market-2-icon.png",
            "http://thecustomizewindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Nicest-Android-Live-Wallpapers.png",
            "http://c.wrzuta.pl/wm16596/a32f1a47002ab3a949afeb4f",
            "http://macprovid.vo.llnwd.net/o43/hub/media/1090/6882/01_headline_Muse.jpg",

    };

    private Constants() {
    }

    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    public static class Extra {
        public static final String IMAGES = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGES";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should likely store the result on a server and then have the device query your server for the result in JSON and then use that collection of images in the JSON data and handle it that way.  Because this result can change you should do it each time your application is started (of course you'd have to tweak this to whatever your extent).

Answer (score 0):

Create file using coma(,)

```
https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q,
https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q,
https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTybItEfE2Xu-Or72BHw8uZf19_mV2Kr8cuuU8kKYrVbeZPXIeX-Q
```

1) Get data from server uploaded file and get response in `res`

2) call method `String filecontentString = readContentFromResponse(res);`

```
public String readContentFromResponse(String res) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(res))));
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("TAG",e);
    } finally {
      if (reader != null) {
        try {
          reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("TAG",e);
        }
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

3) Then create empty String array

```
String[] IMAGES ={};

IMAGES = filecontentString.split(",");
```

Comment: see my updated code in my question and tell me how to Read this file content and store in String object, sample code please